# How to click on the E-Paper link of the first left element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, element, partiallinktext

I used chrome **inspect>select an element in the page** then select it and copy xpath address

and in python use it for click in element but just refresh page and not work

Website url: `https://zeitung.faz.net/`

and I need to click on **E-Paper** using xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]").click()
```

But not click.

Comment: Which element are you trying to click?

Comment: e-paper element

Comment: which e-paper element?  I'm seeing two on the page.

Comment: i work for left element e-paper

Comment: So I tried to manually click the e-paper link on the left, and all that happens is the font changes.  Is something more supposed to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either of the following:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "E-Paper"))).click()
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[normalize-space()='E-Paper']"))).click()
```